# How to fit table column width to size of largest list group item dynamically? CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got a table and in each column and row, there is a list group with several items.

I want to adjust the column width and the width of all the other list groups dynamically to the size of the largest element in the list group. For example, here it is the last "toaster für toastbrot" item.

[Tryit Editor Example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FSJCX669FWJG)

Besides that, if possible, I would like to stay with that width even if I hide some elements using the buttons at the top.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#toggle-buttons label').click(function () {
                $('.list-group-item-' + $(this).attr('toggle')).toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        li {
            line-height: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2 style="display: inline-block;">toaster</h2>
    <div id="toggle-buttons" class="btn-group-toggle float-right" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success active" toggle="success">
            <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off"> NEW
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-danger active" toggle="danger">
            <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off"> DEL
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-warning active" toggle="warning">
            <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off"> CHANGE
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary active" toggle="secondary">
            <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off"> SAME
        </label>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Rev #1</th>
            <th>no newer Rev</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>

                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">
                        <span class="badge">3</span>
                        toaster edelstahl
                        <span class="badge float-right badge-success badge-pill">+3</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                        <span class="badge">4</span>
                        toaster 4er
                        <span class="badge float-right badge-secondary badge-pill">NEW</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">
                        <span class="badge">9</span>
                        toaster rot
                        <span class="badge float-right badge-danger badge-pill">-4</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">
                        <span class="badge">X</span>
                        toaster einhand
                        <span class="badge float-right badge-secondary badge-pill">DEL</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a (qs)</td>
            <td>

                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary">
                        <span class="badge">1</span>
                        toaster wasweißich
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary">
                        <span class="badge">2</span>
                        toaster hype
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">
                        <span class="badge">3</span>
                        toaster edelstahl
                        <span class="badge float-right badge-success badge-pill">+3</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                        <span class="badge">4</span>
                        toaster 4er
                        <span class="badge float-right badge-primary badge-pill">NEW</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary">
                        <span class="badge">5</span>
                        toaster noname
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary">
                        <span class="badge">6</span>
                        toaster ok
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">
                        <span class="badge">X</span>
                        toaster einhand
                        <span class="badge float-right badge-primary badge-pill">DEL</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary">
                        <span class="badge">7</span>
                        toaster mini
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary">
                        <span class="badge">8</span>
                        toaster toast
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">
                        <span class="badge">9</span>
                        toaster rot
                        <span class="badge float-right badge-danger badge-pill">-4</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                        <span class="badge">10</span>
                        toaster für toastbrot
                        <span class="badge float-right badge-primary badge-pill">NEW</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: usually td or table {width:0;} and white-space will do, but the floatting element will do a line break  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FSJDF2DSLJAK  you could think about only inline elements + text-align:justify or dig into flexbox or grid

Comment: .... any feed back or clarification on your question will be usefull for yourself in order to be helped ...

Comment: so for your example it looks quite like what I wanted to achive, what do you mean by the floating element would do a linebreak?